# Using modules in a folder in the same project for Python on IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea, module, jetbrains-ide

So this may be a stupid question but I'm pretty new to programming as a whole.

I like to organize my files in a specific way, but I want to import a module from a separate file for use in my current program, but it isn't recognized. I know I can just put the module I'm using into the file I'm writing in, but I don't want to make a bunch of copies of the module if I use it in other programs as well.

Thanks, don't be too harsh if I'm just being dumb.

Comment: Hi, it would help if you provided your project's structure and code snippets that you use, to identify the issue. By "not recognized" do you mean the code doesn't run? What error do you get?

Comment: I mean showing the code wouldn't really change anything, it's just an import. I get an error saying the module referenced doesn't exist, even though it does, just in a different folder. I was wondering if there was a way to mark that folder for imports.

Comment: Yes, if the module you import is located in a sub directory, you can mark the directory as source root. See:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-structure-dialog.html#7768e64f
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories